# Send log messages from datadog to slack channel

Tags: logging, slack, datadog

Is it possible to send log messages(content in the log message) in Datadog to one of the slack channel? I have tried using the monitors. But there it just provides an alert if log messages exceeds the provided threshold level. I need the exact log message to be sent to the slack channel.

Comment: I have the same use case, don't think it's possible at the moment

Comment: I think this is an obvious gap in their product today. This is super easy to do with, for example, Rollbar.

Comment: @Asokan Kindly check my answer

Answer (score 1):

This can now be accomplished by referencing `{{log.message}}`.

More details are [here](https://docs.datadoghq.com/monitors/notify/variables/?tab=is_alert#matching-attributetag-variables).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: this answer is also based on monitors which will post all messages that occurred within a timeframe (let's say 1 minute) as 1 condensed post to slack which is a poor solution. a proper solution needs to post 1 log entry matching a predicate as 1 slack post

Comment: It can't if the alert is triggered due to a certain metric in an aggregate number of logs. So if you are dealing with many logs, you should first choose a specific one and then retrieve it.